# Exception not caught when using Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I am in a thread which changes data which should be displayed in a dialog (if one is open) so I have the following function:

```
public void UpdateDialog() {
 try {
  if (dlg != null)
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) delegate {
    dlg.Draw();
   });
 } catch {}
}
```

Everything is fine until the user closes the box (in the UI thread). Then dlg may become null after the check and a `NullReferenceException` is thrown which is not caught by the try/catch block.

I'm guessing that `dlg` checked as non-null and is passed to the UI thread which queues up the Draw request. Then the dialog is closed before the Draw method is actually called. Then the UI thread throws the exception which is not caught in the thread I'm in because it was thrown in a different thread.

I've tried putting a lock on the `dlg` property but no change.

Any ideas as to how to handle this? (I just need to ignore the exception because the `dlg` is closed anyway)

[Why is the exception not handled by the Try/Catch block?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9fs1.png)

Comment: If you want to update the UI thread from another thread use `async/await` or the `Progress<T>` class. There's no reason to use `Dispatcher.Invoke`

Comment: The real solution is not to hide the exception, it's modifying the code so there's no exception to begin with, by breaking the coupling between this code and the dialog. What does `Draw()` do and why do you call it in the first place? If the UI need redrawing, it should be in response to a PropertyChanged event, especially in WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being executed in the different thread, so it's not under your try-catch.

This would catch it:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    try 
    {
        dlg?.Draw(); 
    } 
    catch {}
}));
```

Fixed with extra checking for null, as mentioned by @Panagiotis Kanavos

Edit: this is a toy example, please avoid suppressing exceptions in real code, and don't suppress them in the business logic because this could lead to corrupted state.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!  I can't make it fail anymore.  But for laughs, I put a messagebox in the catch block to prove that things were fixed and the messagebox never shows. So I'm still a bit in the dark as to how things are working (and why they are fixed).

Comment: @Charles it didn't, it just covered up the bug. Why do you try take a hard dependency on that dialog to begin with? Why call `Draw()` from a background thread? You can easily remove those dependencies *and* simplify the code *a lot*

Comment: As for this code, the easy fix is to check for null or use `?.`, not hide the bug under the carpet.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks, that's absolutely correct, updated my answer

Comment: You could remove the `try-catch` block. It complicates the code without doing anything useful. The OP probably added this block in an attempt to prevent the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I would keep this in my answer, as there was the question from OP `Why is the exception not handled by the Try/Catch block?`, so I would emphasize how the exception could be caught. And potentially there might be an exception in `Draw` which could lead to unhandled exception and the program termination

Comment: If the `Draw` throws, then an unhandled exception and the termination of the program is the expected outcome. If the `Draw` shouldn't throw, then it should include error handling internally. It is not logical to try-catch every time you call some method. And neither is good practice to swallow exceptions ([`On Error Resume Next`](https://www.google.com/search?q=on+error+resume+next+considered+harmful) in VB).

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions.  Once I add the check for null within the Action (as suggested) all the problems go away away with any need for a try-catch block.